# Проблема с использованием NETSDK1

Tags: winforms, .net-core, .net-7

У меня есть ошибка с файлом расширения csproj с текстом: 
**Поддерживаемая платформа операционной системы не может быть выше чем таргетированная платформа net7.0-windows**

### Сам текст ошибки (на английском)

Error   NETSDK1135  SupportedOSPlatformVersion 10.0.18362.0 cannot be higher than TargetPlatformVersion 7.0.

#### Текст файла настроек csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.22621.755</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.XamlHost" Version="6.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.UI.XamlHost" Version="6.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" Version="10.0.22621.755" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.88.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32" Version="2.88.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views" Version="2.88.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.VCRTForwarders.140" Version="1.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

При попытке билда выводится fail и ошибка описанная ниже:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(188,5): error NETSDK1135: SupportedOSPlatformVersion 10.0.18362.0 cannot be higher than TargetPlatformVersion 7.0.
> Done building project "FinanceApp2.csproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: Есть какие либо проблемы с использованием / совместимостью пакетов NuGet с C#?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70380286/6808809